# Get data from PostGreSQL with Play Framework

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.0

I am new to working under Play Framework with Scala and PostGreSQL and I have a basic question. How can I retrieve all the data stored in the database? I have this piece of code already written:

```
class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends PADT(tag) {
def firstName = column[String]("first_name")
def lastName = column[String]("last_name")
def email = column[String]("email") 

override def * = (id.?,
  firstName,
  lastName,
  email
  ) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply)
}
```

Can you please tell me what is the right syntax to call the * function (I reckon that's what I need to do) and print all the data? Thanks!

Comment: `val users = TableQuery[UsersTable];` and then: `db.run(users.result)` ?

Comment: Also see [Queries, slick documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html)